# How to change status bar clock design

Tags: flutter, flutter-webrtc

How to do like this in flutter I am using flutter/webrtc flutter/callkeep. I want to show onacitve call icon with green background when in webrtc call.

I can only change status bar background color

[image: Active call indicator at statusbar]